# Hadoop Syntax Error When Copying Local files into Hadoop fs

Tags: windows, hadoop

I am trying to copy a set of csv files from my hard drive into a hadoop fs, but I am receiving a Syntax error when I excute the following code:

```
'# hadoop fs -put  'C:\myfolder\myfile.csv'  /user/root/
```

`put: unexpected URISyntaxException`

Is this not the correct syntax?

Comment: Are you using linux or windows ?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal C:\\myfolder\\myfile.csv /user/root/
```

or

```
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal C:/myfolder/myfile.csv /user/root/
```

--NOTE--

Only Full path will work.

Answer (score 0):

I never used put for that...

Try:

`hadoop fs -copyFromLocal C:\myfolder\myfile.csv  myfile.csv`

Comment: Yes I tried that method as well, but I get a different error message: 'Can not create a Path from a null string'

Comment: Are you sure your hdfs is in /user/root?? Try replacing /user/root/ with myfile.csv

Comment: I am fairly certain that the /user/root/ location is hdfs.  I tried replacing the /user/root/ with myfile.csv and I received the same error message I referenced in the comment above.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux env Both syntax should work

```
bin/hadoop fs -put /home/username/Documents/test.csv /usr/test1.csv

bin/hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /home/naveen/username/test.csv /usr/test1.csv
```

The difference between put and copyFromLocal is 
in copyFromLocal **the source is restricted to a local file reference**

Refer this url for shell commands

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.18.3/hdfs_shell.html#copyFromLocal